# All .Net Framework 4 programs failes after recent security update (Net 5+ works)

Tags: windows, windows-10, .net-4.0, .net-4.8

I am battling with a problem, where all programs running by ".Net Framework" fails to start and I am getting (i.e.: Teams/Visual Studio):

---

xx.exe - This application could not be started.

---

This application requires one of the following versions of the .NET Framework:
.NETFramework,Version=v[4|4.6.1|4.5.2|4.8]

Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?

---

Even thought I have .Net Framework 4.8.0 (and 4.8.1) installed. I am running Windows 10 (22H2).

I have tried to rollback the security update (KB5028166)/.Net Framework update (KB5028853, KB5011048), I have tried various "DISM /Online ..." command, "sfc /scannow", "Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool".

What to do? Anybody else experience this problem?

Non .Net Framework programs are working fine, also (Dot)Net5+ are working.

Comment: I ended up resetting my laptop. But later on I think this could have solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935362/servermanager-exe-this-application-could-not-be-started and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/windows-server-2019-and-net-4-8/m-p/2660319

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with update KB5011048. I removed it and "hide" it with "wushowhide.diagcab" tool and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

We had over 50 PC's pop up on July 31 after update were automatically deployed over the weekend. Monday morning all our systems were crashing as the update removed all the SKU's of all the prior versions. We make a regedit import to populate them all back in..there are two locations. one is in the wow6432Node the other is in the 32bit .Net Framework in the reg.

Populate both locations and presto, all working again.

Answer (score 0):

[location1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OShUX.jpg) This covers 32bit apps

[location2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHWrL.jpg) This covers 64bit apps

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you explained what you're pointing out and why. As it is, it's not very helpful in context of the question.